# Convert foreign object to an sfc object [sfc_MULTIPOLYGON, sfc_POLYGON]

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, r-sf

When returning a spatial query from SQL Server I get a data frame where the "Shape" column is a "Character" object and I am unable to turn it into an sfg object.

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(sf)

query_sf.AsText <-  "Select CLASEUSO, Shape.STAsText() AS Shape FROM my_Table where REGION IN ('Region_mh', 'Region_no', 'Region_in')"

query_sf.AsBinary <-  "Select CLASEUSO, Shape.STAsBinary() AS Shape FROM my_Table where REGION IN ('Region_mh', 'Region_no', 'Region_in')"

df_text <- st_read(odbc_con, query = query_sf.AsText)
> Warning message:
> In st_read.DBIObject(odbc_con, query = query_sf) :
> Could not find a simple features geometry column. Will return a `data.frame`.

df_binary <- st_read(odbc_con, query = query_sf.AsBinary)


ex_text <- df_text[1:3, ]
ex_binary <- df_binary[1:3, ]
```

```
str(ex_text)

> 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
> CLASEUSO: chr  "Vegetacion Nativa" "Vegetacion Nativa" "Vegetacion Nativa"
> Shape   : chr  "POLYGON ((-5865371.0349 -2234709.5711000003, -5865383.0660999995 -2234694.5898, -5865392.442 -2234690.814500000"| __truncated__ "POLYGON ((-5866433.0649 -2236171.0835000016, -5866431.4669 -2236170.9224999994, -5866431.1 -2236170.8986000009,"| __truncated__ "POLYGON ((-5864979.8155000005 -2236093.0526, -5865013.8751 -2236072.0670999996, -5865019.1833 -2236072.01419999"| __truncated__
```

STAsBinary does not return the decimal separator.

```
str(ex_binary)

> Classes ‘sf’ and 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
> CLASEUSO: chr  "Vegetacion Nativa" "Vegetacion Nativa" "Vegetacion Nativa"
> Shape   :sfc_POLYGON of length 3; first list element: List of 1
> num [1:184, 1:2] -5865371 -5865383 -5865392 -5865396 -5865401 ...
> attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "POLYGON" "sfg"
> attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "Shape"
> attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA
> attr(*, "names")= chr "CLASEUSO"
```

Converting the text class column into <"XY" "POLYGON" "sfg">
object has not worked.

```
ex_text$Shape <- st_as_sfc(ex_text$Shape)
sf_tbl_text = st_as_sf(ex_text) 
st_crs(sf_tbl_text) = 4326 
sf_tbl_text %>% mapview::mapview()
```

What would be the best way to get an sf data frame ?

Furthermore, the query STAsText() too time consuming.

Comment: what happens if you don't convert your shape to text in your query - `Shape.STAsText()`, and just query the `Shape` column as-is?

Answer (score 2):

The text you are returned from your database seems to follow the [WKT format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry), and as such is not necessarily wrong. It can be handled using standard `sf:st_as_sf()` workflow, pointing `{sf}` to the wkt column.

The one piece of information that is missing is information about coordinate reference system in which should be the polygons interpreted. Going by the number range and my gut I would try Web Mercator / EPSG:3857, but bear in mind that this is just a guess. Is your area of interest in southern Brasil?

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

raw_data <- data.frame(
  claus0= c("Vegetacion Nativa", "Vegetacion Nativa"),
  Shape = c("POLYGON ((-5865371.0349 -2234709.5711000003, -5865383.0660999995 -2234694.5898, -5865392.442 -2234690.814500000))",
            "POLYGON ((-5866433.0649 -2236171.0835000016, -5866431.4669 -2236170.9224999994, -5866431.1 -2236170.8986000009))"))

clean_data <- raw_data %>% 
  st_as_sf(wkt = "Shape", crs = 3857)

mapview::mapview(clean_data) # this not be entirely correct, as the polygons were truncated...
```

[image]